# creating a string from characters(for loop) javascript without methods

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, splice

This is the exercise: Iteration 1: Names and Input
1.1 Create a variable `hacker1` with the driver's name.

1.2 Print `"The driver's name is XXXX"`.

1.3 Create a variable `hacker2` with the navigator's name.

1.4 Print `"The navigator's name is YYYY"`.
Iteration 2: Conditionals
2.1. Depending on which name is longer, print:

- The driver has the longest name, it has XX characters. or
- It seems that the navigator has the longest name, it has XX characters. or
- Wow, you both have equally long names, XX characters!.

Iteration 3: Loops
3.1 Print all the characters of the driver's name, separated by a space and in capitals i.e. "J O H N"

3.2 Print all the characters of the navigator's name, in reverse order. i.e. "nhoJ"

3.3 Depending on the lexicographic order of the strings, print:

- The driver's name goes first.
- Yo, the navigator goes first definitely.
- What?! You both have the same name?

I really don't get point 3.1 and 3.2 without using methods, and since I'm just learning I shouldn't use them.

```
console.log(`The driver's name is ${hacker1}`);

let hacker2 = 'Davide';
console.log(`The navigator's name is ${hacker2}`);

if(hacker1.length > hacker2.length){
console.log(`The driver has ${hacker1.length} characters`);

}else if(hacker1.length < hacker2.length){
console.log(`Yo, the navigator goes first definetely`);
}else{
console.log('What?! You both have the same name');
}


for(i = 0; i < hacker1.length; i++){
    console.log(hacker1[i].toUpperCase())
}
```

I only get 'P''E''D''R''O', but how convert into a string and revere the other name without using methods?

Comment: @AlePlo "without using methods" - but still trivial, create empty string outside of loop, concat the array value's character and the string on each iteration. `+=`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array with a loop. You can define a second array and keep concatenating the characters in this new array.

Result += hacker[i]  while looping through the characters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I still miss the 3.3 point (I am only allowed to use charAt() or splice() if necessary, not others method are allowed.

Here's how I fixed the 3.1 and 3.2

```
let result = '';
for(i = 0; i < hacker1.length; i++){
  hacker1[i];
  result+= hacker1[i].toUpperCase() + ' ';
  }

// 3.2
let reversedName = '';  
for(i = hacker2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  hacker2[i];
  reversedName += hacker2[i];
}
```

How could I do 3.3 with a for loop?